# throwing compilation error when normal lock used

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

I have a class wrapper around posix mutex called LockGuarrd. it was used for a long time and now  I was asked to create another class MyModuleLockGuard that wraps the original wrapper. the new class  should now be used in my module

Is it possible to generate a compilation error in every place that uses the Original LockGuard in my module? I want other people developing not to accidently use it in the future

---

the code is one huge process and each module is a separate code directory. its all being compiled to 1 executable. I am not allowed to change that

the code is all cpp/c compiled with gcc via makefile and scons

Comment: Why do you plan to wrap the old one rather than replacing it? The easiest way to generate a compile error for the old one is remove it.

Comment: I can't remove it because all other modules use it and they all compile together to one big executable. its a workplace code and I am not free to split it into libraries and than link them

Comment: So you want a compiler error when it is used within the module, but not from other modules? This will be tricky from a language point of view, because C++ doesn't have a concept of module.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the header file for the old wrapper in a way that does not affect the runtime operation of the code?

Comment: @SteveTownsend , yes